# why do we simply don't define magnetic induction B to point in the direction of magnetic force that acts in the moving charge

Tags: electromagnetism

Why don't we simply define the magnetic field to point on the direction of magnetic force that acts on the moving charge?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the magnetic force depends on the velocity of the charged particle, so it points in different directions for particles moving in different directions.